# Version control (SVN) of MySQL database in WordPress theme development (any code examples?)

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, version-control, themes

*We deployed an SVN server on Dropbox(!) 
and everything works fine, 
but I'm looking for an easy tutorial

***QUESTION #1: how to version control WordPress database 
for the theme development*** with several developers

Main tasks:

- **Stability**
- **Easy to update**
- **Branch, merge, diff conflicts**

**I've searched a lot of similar topics,**

- but many of them just give an overview,  not tutorials for dummies
- very few of them show how to code those scripts exactly.

---

So here are results of three days of research - almost 20 hours(!)

**QUESTION #2: The scripts (below) are enough for given tasks (above)? or I need to...**

- I need to check triggers, views and strip them (how?)
- This code provides DDL separation (schema and data includes)?
- Is is stable in the long run?

**update.bat**

```
if exist TortoiseProc.exe goto work1
exit

:work1
rem call D:\xampp-themes\mysql_stop.bat
rem ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 3000 > nul
START TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"D:\xampp-themes\htdocs\themes\wp-content\themes\theme1"
rem call D:\xampp-themes\mysql_start.bat
pause
if exist d:\xampp-themes\mysql\bin\mysql.exe goto work2
exit

:work2
d:\xampp-themes\mysql\bin\mysql.exe -u root --default-character-set=utf8 wordpress<"d:\xampp-themes\htdocs\themes\wp-content\themes\theme1\dbcreation.sql"
d:\xampp-themes\mysql\bin\mysql.exe -u root -D --default-character-set=utf8 wordpress<"d:\xampp-themes\htdocs\themes\wp-content\themes\theme1\dbase_data.sql"
rem call D:\xampp-themes\mysql_stop.bat

rem ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 3000 > nul
rem exit
pause
```

**commit.bat**

```
if exist d:\xampp-themes\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe goto work1
exit

:work1
d:\xampp-themes\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe -u root --default-character-set=utf8 wordpress>"d:\xampp-themes\htdocs\themes\wp-content\themes\theme1\dbase_data.sql"
d:\xampp-themes\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe -u root -d --default-character-set=utf8 wordpress>"d:\xampp-themes\htdocs\themes\wp-content\themes\theme1\dbase_structure.sql"
call D:\xampp-themes\mysql_stop.bat
rem ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 3000 > nul

if exist TortoiseProc.exe goto work2
exit

:work2
START TortoiseProc.exe /command:commit /path:"D:\xampp-themes\mysql\data"
START TortoiseProc.exe /command:commit /path:"D:\xampp-themes\htdocs\themes\wp-content\themes\theme1"
pause
call D:\xampp-themes\mysql_start.bat
rem exit
```

All shown above can be pretty lame, but anyway:

---

**Could you suggest a better aproach?**

**Specs:**

- Dropbox as a server on Windows environment (not bash/linux syntax)
- Vanilla WordPress 3.5.1
- XAMPP
- SVN or Subversion with TortoiseSVN Windows client

**Please, provide / edit code! Thanks in advance!**

Comment: SVN server on dropbox? What? 0_0

Comment: yep, and I must say it's working good! ^_^

Comment: Maybe you've just deployed a svn server repository to dropbox storage? It's a different than having a SVN + HTTP (or svnserve) server. There is no authorization, no hook scripts, no *<insert-yourself>*.

Comment: @bahrep i'm not sure how to answer, but here is the tutorial: http://foyzulkarim.blogspot.com/2012/12/dropbox-as-svn-repository.html

anyway this provide us basic and very fast solution for now

Comment: Dropbox will not ensure SVN locking. So you might break your whole SVN repo if you accidentially commit to the Dropbox directory concurrently. Increasing number of developers and number of commits will increase this danger, as will prolonged periods without dropbox access. This does not scale well. Even if it could work, conflict resolution on this beast will be hell. You might want to normalize the SQL dump, e.g. fix sort order, drop unneccessary lines about dates and the like…. Make sure that two subsequent runs on the same data result in the same file, no matter on which machine you do it.

Comment: @MvG, thnx, Dropbox <> Stabilty = understood. Any ideas about DB? All batch files are OK or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main steps:

1. Simplicity. Don't use TortoiseProc, use CLI-client
2. Stability. Don't use Dropbox as repository (or WC) media, select SVN-hosting for your needs
3. Usability. Read about [Luqibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) as DB-versioning and refactoring engine and start using it, adopt workflow for needed changes

Comment: thnx, as mentioned above - copy: Dropbox <> Stabilty = understood. Any ideas about DB? All batch files are OK or ... ?

Comment: @famous - bat-files are **not ideal** (but *may work*), but I strongly suggest to go "Liquibase way" of changing DB - read it's QuickStart, it's easy